Why did Teddy just reveal his true name to Lenny at the end of the movie?
Why did Teddy just reveal his true name to Lenny at the end of the movie Memento? I just find it a cheap and lazy way to connnect the dots that has been set up since the beginning.
Teddy has no reason to say his name is John Gammell during the confession between him and Lenny at the end. He knows Lenny is trying to kill John G so what gives? Why put a target on your back when you confess to a hitman that you are a potential target?
I don't know, I just hope someone smarter than me can enlighten me.

It is a bit stupid of him, but as we see in this scene, he's been 'working' with Lenny for some time and he may have gotten overconfident that he can manipulate him and that he'll quickly forget his name.
